# Grails BuildConfig.groovy, difference between build, compile, and runtime?

Tags: grails, build, compilation, config

What's the difference between `build`, `runtime`, and `compile`, in `BuildConfig.groovy` (1.3.7)

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

    plugins {
        build "acme:acme-cache:latest.integration"
    }

    dependencies {
        build "com.foo.bar:foobar:1.0.5"       
        runtime "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.3"
        compile("com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.3.1")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

- `build` - dependency that is only needed by the build process
- `runtime` - dependency that is needed to run the application, but not compile it e.g. JDBC implementation for specific database vendor. This would not typically be needed at compile-time because code depends only the JDBC API, rather than a specific implementation thereof
- `compile` - dependency that is needed at both compile-time and runtime. This is the most common case

There are a couple of other dependency scopes:

- `test` - dependency that is only needed by the tests, e.g. a mocking/testing library
- `provided` - dependency that is needed at compile-time but should not be packaged with the app (usually because it is provided by the container). An example is the Servlet API

Comment: Thanks, Don, great info, just another quick question...the convention for `build` appears to follow `"groupId:artifactId:repository or version"`, is it the same for runtime and compile as well?

Comment: yes, same convention for all scopes. I never use the `repository` - I didn't even know it existed, so in my case I specify `groupId:artifactId:version`

Comment: We're using Artifactory to store all of our artifacts, so that's why I mentioned it...thanks again!

Comment: @RaffiM you could congigure the repo in the `repositories` section of `BuildConfig.groovy` to avoid having to configure it for each dependency

Answer (score 5):

It seems the 2 previous answers conflict on the distinction between compile and build.  I believe that build is the scope that includes `grails compile` and `grails run-app`, while compile is just the former.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Grails 3, dependencies are managed by Gradle. The `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy` file [has been replaced](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/upgrading.html) by the `build.gradle` file in the project's root.

The Grails user guide [explain how to set grails depencies with gradle](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#gradleBuild). See also the [related Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#configurations) for further details on managing dependencies using it.

Answer (score 1):

A couple grails commands help illustrate the difference. Consider `grails run-app` and `grails compile`. `grails compile` is the compile step and will include compile-time dependencies. `grails run-app` is the run step and will include runtime dependencies. Build dependencies are anything that you might need to run any of these commands, for example, a custom script that hooks into some build events.

So you would pick the one that best fits when you need to be certain the dependency is included.