# different versions of a jar in the classpath

Tags: grails, classpath

Hello this is the followup problem for the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837068/how-does-grails-handle-plugin-dependencies).

I'm creating a Grails Plugin as a wrapper for a complex product. This product has a lot of dependencies to other products like hibernate. The issue is, that grails has some same dependencies but with different Versions. E.g. Grails -> hibernate 3.6.7 other product -> hibernate 3.5.6

I have modified the BuildConfig.groovy as described in the solution:

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
    runtime ('org.ow2.bonita:bonita-server:5.6.1') {
        excludes "slf4j-jdk14"
    }
}
```

Grails has resoved all dependencies and downloaded all required jar to the local repository. STS can resolve all the classes from the dependencies. On run-app there is a problem with hibernate:

```
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.util.SoftLimitMRUCache.<init>(I)V
```

I suppose that the error apears because of multiple hibernate jars in the classpath. How to resolved it?

Thanks in anvance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the fine manual?

http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.7.7%20Plugin%20JAR%20Dependencies

It seems that you need an older version of hibernate in you project. So I guess the solution could be to

- create a plugin project
- remove the hibernate plugin
- drop your jar files into your project
- configure the hibernate jars an `export=false` as described in the documentation (see link above)