# errors when database-migration plugin is defined in BuildConfig

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, database-migration, buildconfig

My attempt to follow suggested good practice and put plugins in `BuildConfig.groovy` instead of `application.properties`, won't work for database-migration. I have tried defining it with scopes of `compile`, `build` and `runtime`. When I run `grails refresh-dependencies`, I get this error message:

> Error WARNING: Specified dependency definition runtime(database-migration:1.3.2) is invalid! Skipping..

(of course, the scope in the message varies with that specified). Is there another scope that I should use, or is this plugin special in some way? It's a shame that the message doesn't say what scopes are valid - that way I wouldn't have to ask this question :-)

I only want to use the plugin in the IDE to generate the xml files, and so I want to exclude it from the war file. Is that what 'export=false' indicates, if the required scope would include it by default?

I have to admit that I can't find a clear definition of the various scopes, and what scope includes what. Can anyone point me at something?

I should add that this is Grails 2.1.1, and GGTS 3.1.

Comment: What _exactly_ did you put in BuildConfig, and where?  Plugin dependencies look like `runtime(':database-migration:1.3.2')` (note the leading colon) and need to go in the `plugins` block, not the `dependencies` one.

Comment: Here's a [good summary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751508/grails-buildconfig-groovy-difference-between-build-compile-and-runtime) of the scopes.

Comment: From my BuildConfig.groovy:

    plugins {
        build(":tomcat:$grailsVersion",
              ":release:2.0.3",
              ":rest-client-builder:1.0.2") {
            export = false
        }
  runtime "database-migration:1.3.2" 
    }
The 'build' entries were generated when I created the project as a plugin.

Comment: @uchamp Thanks for the link. I will bookmark. Though I can't work out if there is a scope that means 'use it for commands, but exclude from the war'.

Answer (score 0):

I have just spotted my error. I hadn't noticed that there is a colon before the name of the plugin. I had:

```
runtime("database-migration:1.3.2")
```

what I should have written is:

```
runtime(":database-migration:1.3.2")
```

A combination of 'Duh!' and what a strange syntax that requires a colon before each term. Oh well, that's how it goes. Reminds me of a time in a customer back in dark ages, when a group of people were poring over a Cobol program that was misbehaving, and no could figure out why. I had a peep, even though I hardly knew Cobol. In a trice, I pointed out that a full-stop was missing after a 'if' statement and before the 'else'. At least a colon has two full-stops, so I may have to acknowledge that my eyesight ain't what it was...