# Grails codenarc script not installing

Tags: grails, plugins, codenarc

I'm using Grails2.3.8 with codenarc 0.21, executing it using

```
grails --non-interactive codenarc
```

To install the codenarc plugin, I have in BuildConfig.groovy, grails.project.dependency.resolution, section plugins, the following:

```
provided ":codenarc:0.21"
```

I've also moved mavenCentral() to be before grailsCentral() in the repositories section (saw a suggestion about that somewhere).

On one machine I faffed around a bit, and it's working.  On the first build on our integration machine I saw it install codenarc the first time it ran, then display a line with:
*codenarc uninstalled*

And now each time it runs I get the error: *Script not found: Codenarc*

I've tried adding

```
grails refresh-dependencies
```

to the build, but no luck.

I expect I could faff around on the build machine and get it to work somehow, but that wouldn't be repeatable in future.

What can I do to make the codenarc plug-in install reliably?

Answer (score 0):

As so often, writing the question prompted me to investigate a different area.

Changing the BuildConfig.groovy, grails.project.dependency.resolution, section plugins, line to:

```
compile ":codenarc:0.21"
```

Fixed the problem - see [Grails BuildConfig.groovy, difference between build, compile, and runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751508/grails-buildconfig-groovy-difference-between-build-compile-and-runtime) for the meanings.

It adds another 4Mb to the build, but I can live with that.  The problem may be a bug in the *provided* implementation in Grails.

- Charles